# Rescaling columns of bootstrapped matrix when using matrix multiplication to compute correlation coefficients

Tags: correlation, bootstrap, matrix, pearson-r

If I have $n$ samples and want to compute the pairwise correlation coefficients between $l$ and $m$ variables, I can construct the matrices $A_{l,n}$ and $B_{n,m}$.  If I then subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation from the rows of $A$ and columns of $B$, the matrix product $AB$ will contain the pairwise Pearson correlation coefficients of my $m$ variables with my $l$ variables.

My question is this: If I want to bootstrap this procedure to get quantiles for each correlation coefficient, is it necessary to rescale the matrices $A$ and $B$ after I sample with replacement the rows of $A$ and columns of $B$, or can I scale once and resample?  My intuition is that the rescaling for every bootstrap iteration is necessary.